# Make error for cross-compiling fontconfig-2.12.1

Tags: arm, fontconfig

I'm trying to cross-compile fontconfig for my embedded Linux arm processor. I was able to perform ./configure but when I try to 'make', after compiling for a while, I've the following errors:

Greatly appreciate anyone's advice!
Thank you!

```
make  all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/aa/Hi3536_SDK_V2.0.4.0/fontconfig-2.12.1'
Making all in fontconfig
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/aa/Hi3536_SDK_V2.0.4.0/fontconfig-2.12.1/fontconfig'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/aa/Hi3536_SDK_V2.0.4.0/fontconfig-2.12.1/fontconfig'
Making all in fc-blanks
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/aa/Hi3536_SDK_V2.0.4.0/fontconfig-2.12.1/fc-blanks'
  GEN      fcblanks.h
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./fc-blanks.py", line 14, in <module>
    from lxml import html
ImportError: No module named lxml
Makefile:595: recipe for target 'fcblanks.h' failed
make[2]: *** [fcblanks.h] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/aa/Hi3536_SDK_V2.0.4.0/fontconfig-2.12.1/fc-blanks'
```

Comment: Make sure you have the `lxml` Python module installed, or install it : `pip install lxml`

Comment: hi schaiba, aft executing the command `pip install lxml`, I've the following error message: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
    from pip import main
ImportError: No module named pip`